# How to Do Matching in Opencv android

Tags: android, c++, opencv, pattern-matching

[image: How to Identify a person using this image]

I'm doing an android project to scan the code card( holding by a girl in above image) and identifying a person.

I searched in google n came to know OpenCV. I'm learning but not getting the idea of how to do. can you please suggest me how to done this in android using OpenCV. sample code will be more helpful.

Comment: Image processing topics like OpenCV is a broad topic and asking for tutorials or sample code is off-topic. To at least give you some direction did you at least find this tutorial: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d5/dae/tutorial_aruco_detection.html. I have the sense that taking a course in image processing will help understand the various tuning parameters available.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and  Think this article will help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact a broad question but if you have the scan of the code card available, then you can do a basic descriptor matching from the *main* image to the code card [Follow this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html) and do the matching using Brute force ( **make sure to match from *main* image to the code card in order to get all the code cards in the main_image** ). Then, you probably have to filter the matches ( using [RANSAC](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_feature_homography/py_feature_homography.html) ). 
The feature matching generally works well for scale/rotation variance however, in the image posted, I see a skewed code cards. This might cause a problem for some cases. 
Hope it helps! Not posting any code, but if you really need I am happy to help!